# give UTC time as name of output file

Tags: python, datetime, utc, writefile

I am writing a code that records some data . I want to record output and automatically give UTC time as name of output file .waiting for idea.

Code:

```
import datetime
for message in range(0,10):

    utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    print 'ambuli', utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
f = open(utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "a") 

f.write(utc_datetime)
f.close()
```

Comment: what do you want your code to do (provide a specific example)? What happens instead? Provide the expected vs. actual ouptut and the full traceback if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need a string (not a `datetime` object) to write to your file.  Try one of these:

```
>>> '%s' % datetime.datetime.utcnow()
'2015-07-16 12:39:13.745780'
>>> '%s' % (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0))
'16632 days, 12:40:20.527201'
>>> '%s' % (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
'1437050431.37'
```

Comment: but output is not text file and it does not write on the file